# Finder-like Browser View

Tags: cocoa, finder, nsbrowser

I have an App that lets the user choose a Browser, or Column View, much like Finder. Since it allows the user to browse a Backup, I'd love to have something like the Finder has in Column view. You select a file, and it shows details about it in the column view, next to the file, like this: 
[image]

My application looks like this, when a leaf is selected: 
[image]

Here, you can see how a sort of Preview/Inspector thing might help. I have it all set up in an NSView, but just have no idea how to add that functionality in there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`-[<NSBrowserDelegate> browser:previewViewControllerForLeafItem:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSBrowserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008275-CH1-SW36)?

Comment: Didn't see that one while browsing through the Docs that were on my computer (Mind you, I was 3 das without internet, terrible, I know) didn't mention that. I'll take a look at it later today.

Comment: I changed my Column View delegate to look like this: http://pastebin.com/m7masnjD and yet I never see the log on the console. What could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: @Tristan that delegate method is for when you're using the item-based delegate methods, which it doesn't look like you are.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should have figured that out a tad sooner.